# Change of Variable for Time Invariance Check

Tags: calculus, signal-processing

I've been studying for a signals and systems class coming this fall and can't figure out how the following change of variable is being applied according to standard definition:
$$T[x(t-\sigma)] = \int_t^0{\tau^2x(\tau-\sigma)d\tau} + x(t-\sigma) $$
$$= \int_{t-\sigma}^{-\sigma}{(\tau' + \sigma)^2x(\tau')d\tau'} + x(t-\sigma)$$
Where the change of variable $\tau-\sigma \rightarrow \tau'$ is applied. 
$$$$